# Python QDialog inherit def from QMainWindow

Tags: class, methods, pyqt, function

I have a Python MainWindow(QMainWindow) class in a file window.py, and i import a Movimentos(Qdialog) from file exportar.py .

When i open Qdialog Movimentos, how do i use a def function that's inside Mainwindow?

Been searching and can't find an answer, sorry if it's been answered.
Would copy the code but its got around 600 lines...have to maintain a project and although i have some experience in python, PyQT is not my forte.

```
class Movimentos(QDialog, Ui_Movimentos):
"""
Class documentation goes here.
"""
def __init__(self,  MainWindow):
    """
    Constructor
    """
    QDialog.__init__(self, MainWindow)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.resize(750, 700)
    #---
    exit=QAction(self) 
    self.connect(exit,SIGNAL('triggered()'),SLOT('close()'))

    self.dteate.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
    self.dteate.setTime(QTime.currentTime())
    self.dteDesde.setDate(QDate.currentDate().addDays(-1))
    self.memcsv = cStringIO.StringIO()
    self.row = []
```

this is from mainwindow where i call Movimentos

```
@pyqtSignature("")
def on_actionMovimentos_triggered(self):
    self.ctimer.stop()
    try:
        self.wndmov = Movimentos(self)
        self.wndmov.exec_()
    except:
        print "sem conexoes ou erro ao abrir janela"
        pass
    self.ctimer.start(60000)
```

Comment: `self.parent().someFunction()`

Comment: Thank you! This is Qt related right? can you advise a good and straightforward book to read?

Comment: The only recent pyqt book I know of is [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html), but I haven't read it myself.